# Include data file as Assemble.io/YAML Front Matter variable

Tags: json, yaml, assemble

I have a `base.hbs` file that does a `{{#foreach}}` loop through some items in an array. That array comes from a YAML/FM variable, set on a per-page basis.

On some pages, that array could be huge, so I'd like to keep it stored in separate JSON file. Is it possible to set a YAML/FM variable to the data contained within a JSON file stored inside my configured `data` folder?

I've tried to do:

```
---
my-array: {{ my-data-file }} 
---
```

...but with no success. It doesn't fail the build, but nothing is there.

**Update**

Alright, so messing around a bit more... turns out even though Assemble via Handlebars can recognize `{{ my-data-file }}`, YAML/FM doesn't like the dashes. It would fail with `'my' is not defined`. So I changed the filename to use underscores, using:

```
---
my-array: <%= my_data_file %>
---
```

I'm keeping this up in case someone else runs into the same issue.